# What are my options when my character is hungry but I have ran out of food?

Tags: adom

I have sometimes found myself in a dungeon with my character hungry and with no food to feed him with. What would be my options, without having to leave the dungeon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kill something and eat it.

How effective that is will depend a lot on your race and what you've killed, but I remember eating a lot of corpses when I was playing.

Comment: Be careful which corpses are you going to digest though! Some might hurt you significantly...

Comment: Oh yea - I had played DCSS before, so was expecting a "chop up" option for the corpses, so I assumed I couldn't eat them, but apparently I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pray and if you have enough piety, your god should make you full.